# Return single cell value from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to ask an question that is an extension on this thread:

[Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas/31296878#31296878).

The code from this thread is listed below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
               'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
               'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8) * 2})
print(df)
#      A      B  C   D
# 0  foo    one  0   0
# 1  bar    one  1   2
# 2  foo    two  2   4
# 3  bar  three  3   6
# 4  foo    two  4   8
# 5  bar    two  5  10
# 6  foo    one  6  12
# 7  foo  three  7  14

print(df.loc[df['D'] == 14])
```

This will yield the following result:

```
   A    B      C   D
7  foo  three  7  14
```

Based on the code above, how can I return a single 'value' not a row. That is, how can I return the value `'7'` or value `'foo'` as opposed to the entire row?

Comment: df.loc[df['D'] == 14][colName] or df.loc[df['D'] == 14].values[index]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

@JonahWilliams was close, here's a working one:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
               'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
               'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8) * 2})

print(df.loc[df['D'] == 14]['A'].index.values)

>>>[7]

print(df.loc[df['D'] == 14]['A'].values)

>>>['foo']
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks very much to both of you.

Comment: These return ndarrays of length 1, rather than the actual values. My solution is min(df['A'][df['D'] == 14]) and this syntax is more logical to me, although using min() seems like a bodge. Surely there is a better way though?

Comment: @smartse - Rather than using `min()`, I'll typically use indexing (`[0]`) to get the **first** value, like this: `df[df['D'] == 14].loc[:, 'A'].values[0]`.  Albeit, I'll only be expecting **one value** to be returned.