# Matplotlib heatmap visualization and Pandas or numpy error: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python Scalars

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a 2D array so I can create a heatmap using `matplotlib.pyplot` similar to the example here: [A simple categorical heatmap](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html)

I have looked at solutions here [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values/31296878#31296878) and here [Return single cell value from Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027643/return-single-cell-value-from-pandas-dataframe), but I cannot get them to work for my purpose.

here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

age = np.unique(ageVehicle['Age'])
vehicle = np.unique(ageVehicle['_Vehicle_Type'])

ageVehicleType = np.array([])
innerList = np.array([])

for i in age:
    for j in vehicle:
        if len(innerList) == len(vehicle) - 1:
            innerList+=(int(ageVehicle.loc[(ageVehicle['_Vehicle_Type'] == j) & (ageVehicle['Age'] == i)]['_Count(vehicle_Type)'].values))
            ageVehicleType.append(innerList)
            innerList = np.array([])
            break
        else: 
            innerList+=(int(ageVehicle.loc[(ageVehicle['_Vehicle_Type'] == j) & (ageVehicle['Age'] == i)]['_Count(vehicle_Type)'].values))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(ageVehicleType)

# We want to show all ticks...
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(vehicle)))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(age)))
# ... and label them with the respective list entries
ax.set_xticklabels(vehicle)
ax.set_yticklabels(age)

# Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

My dataframe `ageVehicle` has 3 columns: `Age`, `_Vehicle_Type` and `_Count(vehicle_Type)`. In the nested for loops `for i ... for j:` I am basically trying to build 1D arrays `innerList` which will be combined together in a 2D array `ageVehicleType`. `age` and `vehicle` lists contain the unique values of age and vehicle in my `ageVehicle` dataframe.

for example:

```
age = [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

vehicle = ['toyota', 'bmw', 'mazda', 'benz', 'tesla']
```

`_Count(vehicle_Type)` is how many of each combinations of age and vehicle there are.

The 2D array `ageVehicleType` will essentially be all possible combinations of `age` and `vehicle` on dataframe `ageVehicle`. This 2D array will be the values to construct the colors on the heatmap.

Questions:

1. The more important question is that I already have the counts (to use for coloring cells on heatmap) in one of the columns `_Count(vehicle_Type`. Is it possible, to somehow use this column in my `ageVehicle` dataframe to build the heatmap instead of creating the 2D array which constitutes all combinations of `age` and `vehicle`?
2. Should the 2D array `ageVehicleType` necessarily be a cross-product of all combinations of `age` and `vehicle`? If so, the logic of the code may need to be altered.
3. I am getting an error. I'd appreciate your help on how I can re-write my conditions to resolve this issue:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-4e2a48f8339f> in <module>
     15         else:
     16             innerList+=(int(ageVehicle.loc[(ageVehicle['_Vehicle_Type'] == j) & (ageVehicle['Age'] == i)]\
---> 17                                  ['_Count(vehicle_Type)'].values))
     18 

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Thanks in advance.